# TimePicker Dialog , adding AM / PM options beside?

Tags: android

I am creating a TimePicker for Alarm, and I have built a timepicker, however it's in 24 hour format , and I'd like to set it in 12 hour format.
I tried to do it in 12 hour format as below:

```
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

But that doesn't give an option for AM PM values. I looked through similar questions here. But there seems a difference in my approach. Advice me with the best fix for this. Here is my Dialog code :

```
public class TimeSetter extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
     }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```